# Understand Modbus RTU CRC

Tags: c, crc, modbus

now I research Modbus RTU and CRC16 of Modbus RTU.

About source code to check CRC, in High-Order Byte Table and Low-Order Byte Table, I don't know how this value generated? In document of Modbus protocol, this has explained: "One array contains all of the 256 possible CRC values for the high byte of the 16–bit CRC field, and the other array contains all of the values for the low byte."

I want how to take this value? Help me, thank you very much.

[Low-Order Byte Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsN59.png)
[High-Order Byte Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynolj.png)

Comment: Document: Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf , page 43/44

Comment: Use `auchCRCLo[0]` to access the first element in that array; or `auchCRCHi[1]` to access the second element in that array. ...

Comment: Can you explained more? These value of array take from???

Comment: Apprently they're constant ... somebody calculated the values (I have no idea how) and pre-filled the arrays in source form.

Answer (score 1):

A description of a bit oriented implementation of the CRC is included in that pdf file, but it could use some cleaning up:

```
1. Load a 16–bit register with FFFF hex (all 1’s). Call this the CRC register.

2. Exclusive OR the first 8–bit byte of the message with the low–order byte
   of the 16–bit CRC register, putting the result in the CRC register.

3. Save the LSB for step 4. Shift the CRC register one bit to the right 
   (toward the LSB), zero–filling the MSB.

4. (If the saved LSB is 0): Continue to step 5.
   (If the saved LSB is 1): Exclusive OR the CRC register with the polynomial
   value 0xA001 (1010 0000 0000 0001).

5. Repeat Steps 3 and 4 until 8 shifts have been performed.
   When this is done, a complete 8–bit byte will have been processed.

6. Repeat Steps 2 through 5 for the next 8–bit byte of the message.
   Continue doing this until all bytes have been processed.

7. The final content of the CRC register is the CRC value.

8. When the CRC is placed into the message, store the low order byte first, and the
   high order byte next.   (msg ... , crclo, crchi).
```

https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf

Note that the bytes of the CRC are swapped in the example code that uses the tables, so what is described as "low byte" is really the "high byte" and vice versa. This is done to allow the CRC to be stored in the message as a 16 bit value on a big endian processor. The bytes would not need to be swapped on a little endian processor, such as a X86 on a PC, since the little endian store will swap the bytes (storing low byte, high byte).

Example code to generate the tables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char    uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short  uint16_t;

uint8_t crclo[256];
uint8_t crchi[256];

    void gentbls(void)
    {
    uint16_t crc;
    uint16_t b;
    uint16_t c;
    uint16_t i;
        for(c = 0; c < 0x100; c++){
            crc = c;
            for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                b = crc & 1;
                crc >>= 1;
                if(b != 0) crc ^= 0xa001;
            }
            crchi[c] = crc & 0xff;
            crclo[c] = crc >> 8;
        }
    }

int main()
{
int i, j;
    gentbls();
    for(j = 0; j < 17; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            printf("%02x ", crclo[j*15+i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%02x\n\n", crclo[255]);
    for(j = 0; j < 17; j++){
        for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            printf("%02x ", crchi[j*15+i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%02x\n", crchi[255]);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00 c0 c1 01 c3 03 02 c2 c6 06 07 c7 05 c5 c4 
04 cc 0c 0d cd 0f cf ce 0e 0a ca cb 0b c9 09 
08 c8 d8 18 19 d9 1b db da 1a 1e de df 1f dd 
1d 1c dc 14 d4 d5 15 d7 17 16 d6 d2 12 13 d3 
11 d1 d0 10 f0 30 31 f1 33 f3 f2 32 36 f6 f7 
37 f5 35 34 f4 3c fc fd 3d ff 3f 3e fe fa 3a 
3b fb 39 f9 f8 38 28 e8 e9 29 eb 2b 2a ea ee 
2e 2f ef 2d ed ec 2c e4 24 25 e5 27 e7 e6 26 
22 e2 e3 23 e1 21 20 e0 a0 60 61 a1 63 a3 a2 
62 66 a6 a7 67 a5 65 64 a4 6c ac ad 6d af 6f 
6e ae aa 6a 6b ab 69 a9 a8 68 78 b8 b9 79 bb 
7b 7a ba be 7e 7f bf 7d bd bc 7c b4 74 75 b5 
77 b7 b6 76 72 b2 b3 73 b1 71 70 b0 50 90 91 
51 93 53 52 92 96 56 57 97 55 95 94 54 9c 5c 
5d 9d 5f 9f 9e 5e 5a 9a 9b 5b 99 59 58 98 88 
48 49 89 4b 8b 8a 4a 4e 8e 8f 4f 8d 4d 4c 8c 
44 84 85 45 87 47 46 86 82 42 43 83 41 81 80 
40

00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 
40 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 
80 41 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 00 c1 81 40 01 
c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 01 c0 80 41 
00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 00 c1 81 
40 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 01 c0 
80 41 00 c1 81 40 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 01 
c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 
00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 
40 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 
80 41 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 00 c1 81 40 01 
c0 80 41 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 
00 c1 81 40 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 
40 01 c0 80 41 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 
80 41 00 c1 81 40 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 01 
c0 80 41 00 c1 81 40 00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 
00 c1 81 40 01 c0 80 41 01 c0 80 41 00 c1 81 
40
```

Comment: wow many thank you, it's very clear and easy to understand